# Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.0.10)

Tags: node.js, rush

Running the application from a bundled file, I'm getting Error: `could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.0.10)`.
This happens when I try to run the application in a virtual machine.

**Info:**

Ubuntu 20.04 lts

Node version: 14.17.5

Npm version: 7.42.0

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib
├── @microsoft/rush@5.53.0
├── node-gyp@8.2.0
├── node-pre-gyp@0.17.0
├── npm@7.24.0
└── yarn@1.22.11
```

Any ideas? Maybe this error means that I am connecting to a JSON-RPC backend that ia either not running or not returning a chain ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error,it is because the address of the RPC Server was incorrect.
Check the address again and try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it is well explained here as you are on wsl ubuntu so ganache must be run on the same

[Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.6.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927795/error-could-not-detect-network-event-nonetwork-code-network-error-version)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34085189)